# proguard bug? removing logs

Tags: android, logging, proguard

My proguard configuration

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

and

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

It does removes most of the logs. However for some logs, it produces strange output as shown below. As you can notice, the Log.d has been replaced by some redundant code.

```
public void MyFunction(int param1, String param2) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MyFunction: " + param1 + " : " + param2);

    ...some code...
}
```

This is transformed to

```
public final void a(int paramInt, String paramString)
{
new StringBuilder("MyFunction: ").append(paramInt).append(" : ").append(paramString);

... some code ...
}
```

}

Any idea what's wrong and how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. You're telling proguard to remove Log.d/w/v/i/e method calls, not the entire line. As far as I know this is the best you can get.
By the way the line `new StringBuilder("MyFunction: ")...` is the result of reverse engineering the bytecode of your class, and it's fine.

I want to give an example of why proguard remove just the method call and not the entire line. Take a look at this snippet:

```
int sum = 0;
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
assert a > 0;
assert b > 0;
Log.d("TAG", "The value of a+b is " + (sum=a+b));
// the sum of two positive number is a positive number
assert sum > 0;
```

What happen if proguard remove the Log.d line?

Comment: I don't think it's fine. I am asking it to remove the line, but not to replace with some redundant code. Indeed limitation.

Comment: You are removing the invocation of the method not parameters that you use inside that method. And you cannot remove them! May I suggest you to use Timber? It's a small logging library that maybe can have better results.